Area of Intersection of Hyperbolic Disks
I am trying to find the area of intersection of two hyperbolic circles using integrals.
The problem:
Let $D_1$ be the hyperbolic disk of radius $R$ centred at $O$. Consider a point $X \in D_1$ at radial distance $r < R$ from $O$ and suppose we construct a second disk $D_2$ centred at $X$ with radius $t$. Assume also that $0 \leq t-r \leq R \leq t+r$. I want to find the area of intersection.
What I have so far:
It is easy to arrive at an integral formula using the hyperbolic law of cosines. The final step to arrive at a solution consists of solving the following integral:
$$\int_{t-r}^R \text{acos}\left(\frac{\cosh(z)\cosh(r)-\cosh(t)}{\sinh(z)\sinh(r)}\right)\sinh(z)dz$$
This is where I am stuck. Any help is appreciated!
